# How to free up space in MCP2515 CAN bus module buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, can-bus, python-can

I've trying some diagnostics over my ECU and for that, I need to send a particular message at every 50ms. I am using MCP2515 CAN BUS module and raspberry pi for communication. The problem is, when the program is initialised it works fine. But after few moments it gives the error,**"Transmit Buffer Full"**. I tried to fix it by increasing the `txqueuelen` to 20000 but still I'm getting the same response.I have even tried the command `bus.flush_tx_buffer` that I found on a website but it seems that it is not working. I have been working over this for past two weeks and searched everywhere on the internet and couldn't find appropriate solution. Please help me out on this. I am using python-can 3.3.4 library for this project.

Here is my code:

```
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel = channel, bustype = bustype, bitrate = 500000)
s_msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x1860, data = [0x15, 0x40, 0x26, 0x90, 0x46, 0x78, 0x53, 0x79], is_extended_id=False)


i=0
while i > 0:

    bus.send(s_msg)
    print(s_msg)
    r_msg = bus.recv()
    print(r_msg)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    bus.flush_tx_buffer()
```

Here is the response when I ran `ip -details -statistics link show can0`

```
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 20000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 2266  bytes 18128 (17.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2266  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: It seems like nobody on the bus is ack'ing your packet and therefore the are pile up on the tx buffer. Is there anybody on the bus? is some node writing a zero (dominant level) on the ack time slot?

Comment: Hello @Fusho, no I don't think the node is writing zero. The node, in response sends back data at very high speed (50ms), could that be the issue?

Comment: In a CAN-bus, if a node sends a packet and nobody acks during the ack-bit timeslot, that packet is assumed to be not successfully transmitted, so it stays on the tx buffer and queued for next pckt transmission: if you write more pkts on the buffer but no one is tx, then the buffer will run out of space. You somebody acking that bit, so the packet can be removed from the tx buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Fusho. Is there any command that can clear the transmit buffer (like the one I used `bus.flush_tx_buffer`)? The one I am using dosen't seems to be doing its job.

Comment: The problem will not be solved by flashing the txbuffer in any case (it will just get full again without tx anything...). If you are on  Linux, could you paste the output of `ip -details -statistics link show can0`, where you have to change `can0` with the name of your interface. Which backend are you using, [socketCan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)?

Comment: Here is the Output. I will be sending it in two parts

``4: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 2000
    link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE restart-ms 0 
   bitrate 500000 sample-point 0.750 
   tq 250 prop-seg 2 phase-seg1 3 phase-seg2 2 sjw 1
   mcp251x: tseg1 3..16 tseg2 2..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..64 brp-inc 1
   clock 4000000 
   re-started bus-errors arbit-lost error-warn error-pass bus-off
   0          0          0          0          0          0         numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1``

Comment: `` gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped missed  mcast   
    1580219    198404   3       18      0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    67776      8472     0       0       0       0 ``

I am using socketCan.

Comment: I would suggest you paste it on your question with good formatting. OTOH, please, execute the command when the buffer is already full (if you are not already...)

Comment: Also, it seems `is_extended_id` should be true since you are using more than 11 bits for `arbitration_id`.

Comment: Okay i'll post it in the question.

Comment: Yes I kept the `is_extended_id true initially, but i got the desired output on standard ID

Comment: Hi @Fusho I have added the response in the question.

Comment: Do you have another device connected?  Are you receiving messages from other devices?  You can't send can messages without another device to ack them.